# Throughput of Aloha

Tags: network-access

The equation for the throughput of Aloha is

S = Ge<sup>-2G</sup>

Which can be thought of as G (the rate of transmission attempts) multiplied by e<sup>-2G</sup> (the probability of one of those attempts being successful).

I came across this graph and text ...

[image: Graph of Aloha throughput]

And it made me question if I really understand what the x-axis represents - offered load.

Why is 0.5 transmission attempts per frame time, referred to as 50% of offered load? (Text above graph).

If there were ten stations and each station attempted one transmission per frame time, would that be 1000% offered load? If yes, why?

I think it's more likely that I have missed a beat somewhere and that I'm not really comprehending what is meant by "offered load".

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [mathcs.emory.edu](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/558/Syllabus/00/CSMA/aloha-anal.html), clarifying some terms:

> > Arrival rate λ = number of new messages that arrives per time unit
> >
> > Offered load (rate) G = number of (old and new) messages that contend for the channel per time unit
> >
> > Throughput S = number of messages that are successfully transmitted per time unit
> >
> > A message is successfully transmitted if its transmission does not collide with any other message transmission

And the offered load `G = λ/P[success]`

> Why is 0.5 transmission attempts per frame time, referred to as 50% of offered load? (Text above graph).

It is just about defining terms (See above linked page for derivation). The packet transmission time is used as time unit here.

> If there were ten stations and each station attempted one transmission per frame time, would that be 1000% offered load? If yes, why?

No. The number of successful/unsuccessful transmissions is also relevant for calculating G. See formula for G.

Thanks,
muehsi